# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when accessing dictionary with non-existent key

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to error handle the userInfo dictionary when receiving a remote push notification, in case the dictionary is missing an expected key.  I keep getting an `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error when I try to do this:

```
if let message = userInfo["key_that_might_not_exist"] as? String {
    // do something
}
```

I thought that if a key does not exist, it would be nil.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why don't you use String? With Swift there is only rare need for NSString.

Comment: are you sure the error is in that line? have you tried setting a breakpoint?

Comment: Why are you downcasting? Subscripting a Dictionary returns a String?, assuming the value type is String.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 if let message:String = a["key_that_might_not_exist"]  {
    // do something
 }
```

Comment: I think that generates a compilation error - maybe an optonal downcast is better

Comment: I used String here while the OP uses NSString (see my comment above).

Comment: But similar code in playground has `AnyObject is not identical to String` error - try yourself: `var t: NSDictionary = ["1": "one"]; if let x: String = t["1"] { }`

Comment: You're probably right. `var a:[String:AnyObject] = ["Some":"Val"]`defined and executing
`if let message = a["key_that_might_not_exist"] as? String { ... }` works with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use a `String`; I do not think you need to have that specific thing as an `NSString`.

Second, are you sure `userinfo` exists? You could easily be setting the post wrong. Try wrapping it in:

```
if let dictionary = userInfo {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

is your userInfo really not nil?

```
if let userInfo = notification.userInfo as? Dictionary<String,NSObject> {
    if let message = userInfo["key_that_might_not_exist"] as? NSString {
        ...
    }
}
```